# String resource not found in kotlin android with getPageTitle

Tags: android, kotlin

New to android and kotlin here. Making my first app and I'm trying to use the `getPageTitle` function to give my tabs their titles (of which are string resources). The full implementation is as follows:

```
class FAAMainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar as Toolbar)

    val pagerAdapter = SectionsPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager, FragmentPagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT)
    pager.adapter = pagerAdapter
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(pager)
}

private class SectionsPagerAdapter : FragmentPagerAdapter{

    constructor(fm: FragmentManager, behavior: Int) : super(fm, behavior)

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        when (position) {
            0 -> return HomeFragment()
            1 -> return KittensFragment()
            2 -> return CatsFragment()
            3 -> return FosterersFragment()
            4 -> return FAAUsersFragment()
            else -> {
                return HomeFragment()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return 5
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        when(position) {
            0 ->  Resources.getSystem().getText(R.string.home_tab)
            1 ->  Resources.getSystem().getText(R.string.kitten_tab)
            2 ->  Resources.getSystem().getText(R.string.cat_tab)
            3 ->  Resources.getSystem().getText(R.string.fosterer_tab)
            4 ->  Resources.getSystem().getText(R.string.faa_user_tab)
            else -> "Error"
        }
        return "Error"
    }
}
}
```

Trying to run the application gives the following error:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{uk.ac.aber.dcs.cs31620.faa/uk.ac.aber.dcs.cs31620.faa.ui.FAAMainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f0d0027`

I don't understand why it cannot find the String resource.

My strings.xml;

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Feline Adoption Agency</string>
    <string name="hello_blank_fragment">Hello blank fragment</string>
    <string name="home_tab">Home</string>
    <string name="kitten_tab">Kittens</string>
    <string name="cat_tab">Cats</string>
    <string name="fosterer_tab">Fosterers</string>
    <string name="faa_user_tab">FAA Users</string>
</resources>
```

More information as I am putting a bounty on this:

- I can verify the resources are being placed in the `app/build/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/debug/r/uk/ac/aber/dcs/cs31620/faa/R.java` file correctly.
- However they are not put into the `app/build/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/debug/r/androidx/appcompat/R.java` and I am not sure that is the cause of the issue.
- My imports for the `FAAMainActivity` class are:

  `import android.content.res.Resources
  import android.os.Bundle
  import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
  import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
  import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
  import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
  import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter
  import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
  import uk.ac.aber.dcs.cs31620.faa.R
  import uk.ac.aber.dcs.cs31620.faa.ui.cats.CatsFragment
  import uk.ac.aber.dcs.cs31620.faa.ui.faa_users.FAAUsersFragment
  import uk.ac.aber.dcs.cs31620.faa.ui.fosterers.FosterersFragment
  import uk.ac.aber.dcs.cs31620.faa.ui.home.HomeFragment
  import uk.ac.aber.dcs.cs31620.faa.ui.kittens.KittensFragment`

I've uploaded the project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VZSpPMu-KQ98fiUS8B1fZUskFAIH2MLB/view?usp=sharing) if anyone want's to try it out.

Comment: Not sure if related but you are missing the `return` on your `when` statement on your `getPageTitle()`

Comment: Didn't know you could do that in Kotlin but sadly having it `return when` didn't change anything. Useful to know tho.

Comment: This can occasionally happen with resource ID generation. Typically just doing a full clean and rebuild will fix it.

Comment: Have you tried using `context.getString(R.string.bla_bla)`?

Comment: Why do you use `Resources.getSystem().getText`? Have you tested `context.getString`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling `Resources.getSystem()` provides System level resources and not your 
application level resources as per the doc:

> Return a global shared Resources object that provides access to only
>   system resources (no application resources), and is not configured for
>   the current screen (can not use dimension units, does not change based
>   n orientation, etc).

You'll need application or activity level context in order to retrieve the strings from your strings.xml. I have changed your `SectionsPagerAdapter` to this in order to fix your error:

```
private class SectionsPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager, behavior: Int, private val context: Context) :
        FragmentPagerAdapter(fm, behavior) {

        override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
            return when (position) {
                0 -> HomeFragment()
                1 -> KittensFragment()
                2 -> CatsFragment()
                3 -> FosterersFragment()
                4 -> FAAUsersFragment()
                else -> {
                    HomeFragment()
                }
            }
        }

        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return 5
        }

        override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
           return when(position) {
                0 ->  context.getString(R.string.kitten_tab)
                1 ->  context.getString(R.string.kitten_tab)
                2 ->  context.getString(R.string.cat_tab)
                3 ->  context.getString(R.string.fosterer_tab)
                4 ->  context.getString(R.string.faa_user_tab)
               else -> context.getString(R.string.home_tab)
            }
        }
    }
```

**FAAMainActivity**

```
val pagerAdapter = SectionsPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager, FragmentPagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT, this) // Passed "this" as context
```

Here, I have primarily changed following things in your code,

**From**

```
private class SectionsPagerAdapter : FragmentPagerAdapter{

    constructor(fm: FragmentManager, behavior: Int) : super(fm, behavior)
    ...
}
```

**To**

```
private class SectionsPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager, behavior: Int, private val context: Context) :
        FragmentPagerAdapter(fm, behavior) {
        ...
}
```

I have changed your JAVA style constructor to kotlin's primary constructor and added `Context` as third parameter. Now we will use that `Context` to get the string instead of `Resources.getSystem()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.faa_user_tab)
```

instead of

```
Resources.getSystem().getText(R.string.faa_user_tab)
```

Comment: Sadly this didn't work, nor did a clean and rebuild like Nathan above suggested.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the documentation of [Resources](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources), the method [getSystem()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getSystem()):

> Return a global shared Resources object that provides access to only
>   system resources (no application resources), is not configured for the
>   current screen (can not use dimension units, does not change based on
>   orientation, etc), and is not affected by Runtime Resource Overlay.

So you cannot access your application resources by this method. But looking at your code you can simply change

```
private class SectionsPagerAdapter
```

to:

```
private inner class SectionsPagerAdapter
```

and when you want to get the string instead of

```
Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.kitten_tab)
```

do this:

```
getString(R.string.kitten_tab)
```

**Explanation:** When you mark a class as `inner` you are making every method along with other things in outer class visible and accessible in the [inner class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html). In every [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity) (any [Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html)) there are methods for accessing resources. One of them is `getString` which you can simply use to [get your strings](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString(int)) by their id.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm not answering your question directly but the issue can be solved by changing the way you create/use the adapter.

The main change is that instead of letting the adapter decide how to populate the view we give that "responsibilty" to the user.

We do that by requesting a list of pages, in this example I used a `Pair<String, Fragment>` but you can create an actual data model with all the necessary information you need.

```
class SectionsPagerAdapter(
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
    behavior: Int,
    val pages: List<Pair<String, Fragment>>
) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fragmentManager, behavior) {

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment = pages[position].second

    override fun getCount(): Int = pages.size

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence = pages[position].first
}
```

And when you are creating the adapter you create it inside your `Activity/Fragment` like this

```
val pages = listOf( /* Change the list to fit your exact needs*/
    context.getString(R.string.kitten_tab) to HomeFragment(),
    context.getString(R.string.kitten_tab) to KittensFragment(),
    context.getString(R.string.cat_tab) to CatsFragment(),
    context.getString(R.string.fosterer_tab) to FosterersFragment(),
    context.getString(R.string.faa_user_tab) to FAAUsersFragment()
)

val adapter = SectionsPagerAdapter(
    supportFragmentManager,
    FragmentPagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT,
    pages
)
```

This way, you do not only solve the problem, but you also achive a scalable solution that supports not only this use case but any other use case

Answer (score 0):

The code that works with your method are :

```
Resources.getSystem().getText(android.R.string.cancel)   // returns Cancel 
Resources.getSystem().getString(android.R.string.cancel) // returns Cancel 
Resources.getSystem().getResourceName(android.R.string.cancel)) //returns android:string/cancel
Resources.getSystem().getResourceEntryName(android.R.string.cancel)) returns cancel
```

But in all the cases the string used starts with **android.R** that means you can access only the **androids built in resources** using these methods.

I dont know why you are trying to access your string resource using the above method.

Below I have listed certains methods to access your app related resources :

```
getResources().getText(R.string.app_name)); // returns Test App
getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)); // returns Test App
getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.string.app_name)); // returns app_name
getResources().getResourceName(R.string.app_name)); //returns com.example.testapp:string/app_name
context.getText(R.string.app_name)); // returns Test App
context.getString(R.string.app_name)); // returns Test App
```

Also you can use the **context** to access the methods starting with **getResources()** as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are calling the string resources in a wrong way. it should be something like  this:-

```
override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
    when(position) {
        0 ->  getString(R.string.home_tab) // just call getString() bcz, calling from AppCompatActivity
        1 ->  getString(R.string.kitten_tab) // if you use fragment and try to call 
        2 ->  getString(R.string.cat_tab) // getString(), use resources.getString(...)
        3 ->  getString(R.string.fosterer_tab)
        4 ->  getString(R.string.faa_user_tab)
        else -> "Error"
    }
    return "Error"
}
```